# Access text fields that call VBA functions not displayed

Tags: ms-access, vba, office365

An organisation I assist with Access development recently upgraded from Office 2010 to Office 365.
Since the change, databases no longer displays any of the text fields that call VBA functions for their value.
A simple example:  One form has a textbox with a Control Source set to "=GetVersionTitle()" which is a simple VBA function that returns a concatenation of strings.

When I open this form on my local machine which runs Office 2013 it displays all fields correctly but when it is opened in Office 365 version of Access the field is blank until you click in the field and then the code is run and the result displayed.  In addition to the above the Access status bar at the bottom of the screen constantly displays calculating...

I have checked that all the VBA code compiles and that it is not missing any references. I have tried compact and repair on the database. shutdown and restarted the computer.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated

Edit: In trying to diagnose the issue I have found that pressing F9 will force the forms to calculate the values and run any of the procedures that did not run when the form was opened.  The behaviour is very similar to what happens if you turn off auto calculate in Excel, but I am not aware of any such setting in Access.

Comment: What happens if you create a sub procedure for that textbox and say something like Me.txtName.Value = GetVersionTitle ?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to make any difference.  Some of the calculated fields are triggered in code by procedures and these do not calculate either in fact the code does not even run unless the actual calculated field gets the focus or you press F9

Comment: I would do a de-compile. And then re-compile.

Comment: Tried the decompile and compile trick even considered the full copy to another database but the issue looks to be machine specific not database specific.  I have now had a user from another state in the same organisation try the database and it all works fine.  I am starting to suspect a bad install of Office on the SOE used in the office.  I have requested the IT division to re-install office on at least one machine and I will update with the results.

Comment: P.S.  Thanks everyone for the suggestions so far I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could provide a better answer than this but at least the issue has been resolved.

The calculation issue was a side effect of a change one of the network administrators made in the Group Policy during a recent network upgrade.

Unfortunately the network administrators will not provide me with any more details than that.  Once the policy was changed and all computers were restarted to load the new policy, the calculations all started working again.

No change to the database was required.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all of the ins and outs of the function, it sounds like Access is loading the form faster than it can pull the function.

You could add a 2 second delay timer on form load, after which it requeries the field.